# how to add constant decimal value to hexadecimal value without conversion?

Tags: decimal, hex

Say if I want to add `4` to a hexadecimal value `F9E` then I will get `FA2`.

one way of doing it is by converting `F9E` to decimal and then add `4` to that decimal value and then reconvert the new decimal value to hexadecimal value.

Is there any other shortcut way to do this?

Comment: are you asking how to do this on paper?

Comment: you'd eliminate a step by converting the decimal number to hex and then adding that.  otherwise you're looking at converting back and forth, or converting to a common base (ie, binary)

Comment: @RyanHaining: you mean to say that I should convert `4` to hexadecimal and then add it to `F9E`

Comment: yeah, since your current approach involves two conversions, that would only need one.

Comment: that's assuming you can do math in hex easily enough.

Comment: @RyanHaining: what is 4 in hex

Comment: 4, would be written as 0x4

Answer (score 1):

You can change it to binary and then add the binary numbers

that is:

```
4 in binary: 000000000100

FA2 in binary: 15 10 2 => 1111 1010 0010
```

Then make binary addition:

```
000000000100 / 111110100010 => 111110100110 = 4006.
```

4006 in hex is FA6

Buts its not really a shortcut ;-(